# Trouble binding XML child to DataList using ReadXML()

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, data-binding

I am trying to bind an ASP DataList control with the values returned from an XML file. What's somewhat unique is that I'm not loading the XML from a file, but rather using XMLTextReader() to load it as a string. The reason for this is that the XML will be built from values read from the database. Here's the code which takes (in this case a hard-coded) XML string, adds it to a DataSet and then binds the DataList control...

```
StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();

    xml.Append("<product>");
    xml.Append("<sku>241</sku>");
    xml.Append("<prodID>2SIDED</prodID>");
    xml.Append("<name>Product Name</name>");
    xml.Append("<price>6.99</price>");
    xml.Append("<description>Product Description</description>");
    xml.Append("<standalone>1</standalone>");
    xml.Append("<sellable>1</sellable>");
    xml.Append("<product-type>10</product-type>");
    xml.Append("<customization>");
    xml.Append("<option1></option1>");
    xml.Append("<option2></option2>");
    xml.Append("<option3></option3>");
    xml.Append("</customization>");
    xml.Append("</product>");

using (XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml.ToString())))
    {
        var document = XElement.Load(tr);
        string source = document.ToString();
        DataSet dsProdList = new DataSet();
        dsProdList.ReadXml(new StringReader(source));
        prodDetail.DataSource = dsProdList;
        prodDetail.DataBind();
    }
```

Here's the DataList control...

```
<asp:DataList ID="prodDetail" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="prodDetail_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="proddetail">
            <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" width="480" height="325" AlternateText='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>'/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnStandalone" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "standalone") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSellable" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sellable") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTypeId" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "product-type") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOption1" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "option1") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOption2" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "option2") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnOption3" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "option3") %>' Visible="false" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "description") %>'>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

This seems to be working fine until the code attempts to bind "option1" at that point I get the following exception: 
**DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'option1'.**

From what I can work out this definitely seems to be an issue with "option1" being a child of "customization". If I simply comment out the opening and closing "customization" tags, which effectively leaves the "option(s)" as children of "product" the code runs fine and I get the output I'm expecting.

Is there any way I can format the DataBinder.Eval() to see the child item? If so, I can't figure it out and hours of searching having been unsuccessful. Or should I be tackling this differently? Perhaps not using a DataSet? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `xDoc` and `linq` and `anonymous` type as,

```
prodDetail.DataSource = from item in xDoc.Descendants("product") 
        from needThis in item.Descendants("customization")
        select new 
        {       ProductName = item.Element("sku").Value,
                ID = item.Element("prodID").Value,
                //----other properties----
                Option1 = needThis.Element("option1").Value,
                Option2 = needThis.Element("option2").Value,
                //---and some more properties----
        };
```

you have to make sure you give the property names of the `anonymous` object same as the property names you are expecting in the databind in `datalist`.

Comment: That does the trick, Thanks Coder of Code! I had tried a similar solution using linq and while it did not throw any errors it also did not return any results. Using XDocument was the key here. Thanks again!